# Filling Gaps with Rectangles & Triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles, rectangles

I'm quite new to Stack Exchange, and I also wasn't too sure where I should post this. This came up for me when I was doing some programming for a small game-project, and the task I found myself thinking of seemed somewhat mathematical in nature, and maybe perhaps common within geometry? I know very little about math though, which is why I'd thought of asking here in case

The task I was thinking of is that:- Given a square-sized space with some variable amount of squares inside of it (none of these squares inside the space overlapping with each other, all squares fully contained inside the space, and each of these squares being able to be in different rotations):- the task being to write some general algorithm that can tell you, with detail regarding positioning and sizes, how the spaces and holes between the squares can be filled with rectangles and triangles carefully arranged

[image: A quick drawing I made] (a quick drawing I'd made; it's pretty bad)

I hope this doesn't come off as a homework question or anything- I am genuinely curious of how a mathematician/maths person might approach this?

Comment: Triangulation is easy; you won't even need rectangles. Wait... is it by chance that all your triangles seem to be right-angled, or is that a requirement too?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Oh, I hadn't noticed that all my triangles happened to be right-angled; I'd be interested in any kind of solution with rectangles or triangles! And I also didn't realize it should just boil down to triangles, since any rectangle can be split into two triangles.. (duh! I'm dumb.) But could you enlighten me on how the triangulation could be done? I'm pretty bad when it comes to math

Comment: Connect any two vertices of your squares (presumably the nearest two to each other, but the strategy may vary), so as not to intersect any other squares. Repeat. Continue to do so, until there are no more vertices visible from each other. That's a triangulation, one of many possible.